# How do we set the width of page in HorizontalPager in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm using HorizontalPager in jetpack compose. I want to set the page height to available screen and page width should be 70% of the width. I tried setting .fillMaxWidth(0.7f) to horizontalPager its setting the width of whole Horizontal pager but i want to set the width of page.

I want the result like this

[image]

I tired this code

```
     HorizontalPager(
        state = pagerState,
        pageSize = PageSize.Fill,
        contentPadding = contentPaddingValues
    ) { page ->
        val media = mediaList[page]
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .graphicsLayer {
                    val pageOffSet = (
                            (pagerState.currentPage - page) + pagerState
                                .currentPageOffsetFraction
                            ).absoluteValue
                    alpha = lerp(
                        start = 0.5f,
                        stop = 1f,
                        fraction = 1f - pageOffSet.coerceIn(0f, 1f)
                    )
                }
        ) {
                AsyncImage(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize(),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                    model = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
                    .data(media.uri)
                    .crossfade(true)
                    .build(),
                    contentDescription = null )
        }
    }
```

But unfortunatliy i m getting this result  :

[image]

Comment: contentpadding horizontal centers the page item. You can specify the item spacing as well. Play with contentPadding and item spacing

Comment: also i feel card is not necessary if you just want to display image with rounded corners